# Is there a way in DataDog to include current date in monitor query?

Tags: datadog

I have a monitor that runs every 24hrs. I want to include the date (on which the monitor runs) in the query of the monitor. E.g.

```
{
    ...
    "type": "log alert",
    "query": "logs(\"service:foo env:prod \\\"Some log message.\\\" @SomeField:2024-12-15\").index(\"*\").rollup(\"count\").last(\"1d\") < 6",
    ...
}
```

I'm creating these monitors from code using this way:

```
import { Monitor } from '@cdktf/provider-datadog/lib/monitor';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export function FooMonitors(context: Construct): void {
  new Monitor(context, `Monitor name`, //monitorJsonFromAboveGoesHere);
}
```

Is there a way to substitute `@SomeField:2024-12-15` to something like `@SomeField:$dateOnWhichMonitorRuns`, so that this date updates every day? Or is there an alternative way to approach this issue?

I looked through the docs but haven't found a way to do this.